# override __str__ method that allow display conditionnal string based on browser language

Tags: python, django

I have a Django project that is internationalized

I have a model Pays that contain 2 fields (french and english) to manage translation

In my form, I have a ModelChoice Field that display a list of country in french

How can I manage language in Pays model **str** method ?

```
def __str__(self):
    return f"{self.pay_nom_eng}"
```

```
...
self.language = request.session.get('language')    
PAYS = Pays.objects.filter(pay_ran = 1).order_by('pay_ide')
...

self.fields["pay_ide"] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = PAYS, label = _("Country"), widget = forms.Select)
```

Answer (score 0):

firstly i think you shoud have look at django-translations library, which can do lovely job for you and save a lot of time.

anyway to answer your question you can have look to doc i think its pretty clear about this :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelChoiceField.iterator